# How to choose between two possible arrangements of tapered roller bearings?

Tags: bearings, machine-design

I don't know how to decide between the $X$ and $O$ arrangement, i don't have any specific example at this moment, but i want to know.

Catalogues offer only some basic calculations. I'm not quite sure if there any guidelines or instruction exist, i have already consulted many books, but so far my researches failed to help me justify the choice between the two arrangements.

[image]

Source: https://debearings.se/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/12-Tapered_roller_bearings.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The arrangement on the left is often used for fully floating hubs on vehicle axles, as the end float is easily set and controlled.

Comment: Thank you, this is very specific example, however i'm searching for a more general guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you download the Timken roller bearing technical manual as it goes through the process of designing with TRBs in some detail . O type is stiffer in coning than X type, which might be an advantage if you were designing a machine tool for example, but would reduce the bearing life if the shaft flexes.

https://www.timken.com/resources/timken-engineering-manual/